# Twill CMS 2.x, File and Medias upload using media library in the same form

Tags: laravel, media-library, twill, imgix

I am using Twill CMS with Laravel, and I have a form where images are uploading correctly.

Now, I want to upload files/videos in the same form, but I am struggling with the configuration to do it properly. Could you please guide me on how I can upload both images and files/videos together in the same form?[this is my twill.php file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wru3J.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZINtH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF41L.png)

I attempted to upload both images and files/videos in a Twill CMS form within Laravel. I expected that I could configure the form to allow for the simultaneous upload of images and files/videos. However, I encountered issues with the configuration, and it did not work as expected.

I hope to get guidance on how to successfully enable the uploading of both images and files/videos in the same form.